# Bootstrap image gallary section

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a section in my site  that should stretch all the way across the screen.

I want to add 4 images in this section, one beside the other, and make them responsive. I want them to fill the background and breaks between them as needed. How should I modify my code below to accomplish the effects I desire?

```
 #games {
    background-color: #000;
}

#games img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.4columns {
  width: 32%;
  display: inline-block;
}

<section id="games" class="section section-games">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
          <a href="" target="_blank"><img class="4columns" src="resources/media/icons/1.png"></a>
          <a href="" target="_blank"><img class="4columns" src="resources/media/icons/2.png"></a>
          <a href="" target="_blank"><img class="4columns" src="resources/media/icons/3.png"></a>
          <a href="" target="_blank"><img class="4columns" src="resources/media/icons/4.png"></a>
        </div>
      </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Read : [When someone answers your question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want something like this :

```css
.map{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

.map img{
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
}
```

```html
<div class="map">
    <span>
        <img src="http://www.inkntoneruk.co.uk/ink-cartridge-news/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/LOTRFOTRmovie.jpg" />
        <img src="http://www.inkntoneruk.co.uk/ink-cartridge-news/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/LOTRFOTRmovie.jpg" />
        <img src="http://www.inkntoneruk.co.uk/ink-cartridge-news/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/LOTRFOTRmovie.jpg" />
        <img src="http://www.inkntoneruk.co.uk/ink-cartridge-news/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/LOTRFOTRmovie.jpg" />
    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Ani Menon I looked at that but what i need is for the 4 images to fill all the way across like a bg image but all for fill the whole section

Comment: I only have 4 thats it

Comment: Ani Menon I have 4 images picture this a background image split in 4 sections with no space between them

Comment: If you want 4 images like that, then you need four images which are long & not wide.

Comment: I have the images the code above shows them much smaller

Comment: Ani Menon it almost works theres a 20px gap on the left margin and it adds bottom scroll bars and full image to the right

Comment: @Roman thats my second code snippet which is actually better responsive with bootstrap(you may improve on this). **Check my first snippet**.

Comment: So that's your answer. Copy the other snippet from edit history if you want to. (I shall remove the second snippet.)

Comment: Ani Menon it shrinks the whole section not the images

Comment: You want the images shrinked? That would look bad. [Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/cTxYc/3300/) or [this](http://jsfiddle.net/cTxYc/3301/)

Comment: Ok i dont want the image to shink all 4 on the same row there is no break so when you look at the image in mobile its so small you cannot read it

Comment: @Roman I have put up two complete solutions for you. If you are still not satisfied. Hire a web designer.

Comment: they may have been complete to you however they were not complete to me.. cause a overflow scroll of about 500 px with a 20px indent is not a complete solution.. what i need and you have given is 2 totally different things

Comment: I think the above snippet answers your question. If you don't find it useful. Bye bye.

Comment: Ani Menon run your own code for me and tell me where the images break? and you will see they dont break.. they stay side by side the whole way shrinking down